# In Python how to find max length of inner list in a 2D list?

Tags: python, numpy

I often create a list of lists with varying length of inner list, for e.g. to represent a bunch of sentences of varying length

```
[['Hello', 'world'], ['how','are','you'], ['have','a','good','day']]
```

I need these to be converted to numpy matrix. To make all inner lists of same length I pad a dummy element at the end and make all inner lists equal the maximum length.

Is there any compact way of finding the max length of inner list?

I usually do it by writing a for loop and keeping track of the max length but I do it so often that I feel the need for a better way.

Comment: What about writing a function?

Comment: How is this `numpy`? the list contains strings, not interger

Comment: Pad without explicitly calculating longest: `np.array(list(itertools.zip_longest(*alist, fillvalue='dummy'))).T`

Comment: @U9-Forward sorry I forgot to mention I use word embedding like GloVe to replace each word with a vector, that's where I use numpy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function:

```
max(your_list, key=len)
```

You will get the longest list, if you need the actual length just use `len` again:

```
len(max(your_list, key=len))
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/SuddenSingleSuperuser)

Answer (score 4):

Using `map` and `max`, you find the max length of the sub lists easily

```
>>> max(map(len, lst))
4
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like the following:

```
max([len(item) for item in A])
```

Comment: better as a generator than using an intermediate list

Answer (score 2):

And order it:

```
>>> A=[['Hello', 'world'], ['how','are','you'], ['have','a','good','day']]
>>> sorted(A,key=len)
[['Hello', 'world'], ['how', 'are', 'you'], ['have', 'a', 'good', 'day']]
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert your list of lists in a numpy array, you can try the following snippet. The fourth line pads your data and the fifth line creates the numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
data=[['Hello', 'world'], ['how','are','you'], ['have','a','good','day']]
max_length = max(map(len, data))
[e1.extend(['']*(max_length - len(e1))) for e1 in data]
np_data=np.array(data)
```

Comment: don't use list-comprehensions for side-effects.